# Dependencies not supporting DNXCore Framework version and namespaces not found errors

Tags: asp.net, api, dnx

I created a brand new ASP.NET Web API project from scratch.  I selected an ASP.NET v5 blank Template and added nothing.  My default `project.json` file looked like so:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

I then went to the NuGET package installer and added `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi` and straight away I am presented with errors in the compiler:

[image]

[image]

I am finding this is occurring for a lot of packages I am trying to install (even the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage` package gives me the same errors).  I am also trying to add `DbModelBuilder` to my classes which throws similar results (which makes me think something is corrupt somewhere):

[image]

My updated `project.json` file now looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi": "5.2.3"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Data.Entity": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

As I am setting this up a a brand new project, I am a little confused as to what I am doing wrong or if my installation of Visual Studio is messed up.  It's making it impossible to follow any tutorials online due to all the errors I'm faced with.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With MVC6, Web API and MVC have merged. So there's no need to install  a Web API NuGet package. You should however install [MVC 6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/6.0.0-rc1-final). There are a lot of other changes with .NET, and I suggest you take a time to do some research on it before jumping in. A lot's moved around. See also [Building Your First Web API with MVC 6](http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/getting-started/first-web-api.html).

Comment: That was the tutorial I first followed, and going back to it still doesn't seem to resolve my issues.  I still can't add a `DbModelBuilder` without errors and without it, I know how to create database relationships for my SQLite framework.

Comment: I sort of believe that VS 2015 team released their product without any testing.